# Thread Usage In Cpu For .Net Apps

Tags: c#, multithreading, iis, cpu

Hi I am reading about Threads and IIS. And it is told that each requests executed by a thread on cpu. And each logical processor can have one thread. So I tried that. My computer has 4 logical processor and I run an console app that created 4 tasks with this code.

```
        Task raskRun1 = new Task(() => run1());
        raskRun1.Start();

        Task raskRun2 = new Task(() => run2());
        raskRun2.Start();

        Task raskRun3 = new Task(() => run3());
        raskRun3.Start();

        Task raskRun4 = new Task(() => run4());
        raskRun4.Start();
```

And each has this implemantaion.

```
    public static void run1()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("1" + i.ToString());
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }

    }
```

What I expect that is, while running this application. I cannot load my locale web app. But it is loading.

I know my thought are wrong but can you explain a bit this case please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each logical processor can run one thread at any specific moment, but can run multiple threads concurrently by allocating time slices to each one.

> A multitasking operating system divides the available processor time among the processes or threads that need it. The system is designed for preemptive multitasking; it allocates a processor time slice to each thread it executes. The currently executing thread is suspended when its time slice elapses, allowing another thread to run. When the system switches from one thread to another, it saves the context of the preempted thread and restores the saved context of the next thread in the queue.
>
> The length of the time slice depends on the operating system and the processor. Because each time slice is small (approximately 20 milliseconds), multiple threads appear to be executing at the same time.

[Multitasking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/procthread/multitasking)